# How to run Wilcoxon and cliff.delta on column with specific criteria?

Tags: r, filter

I want to run a wilcoxon test and Cliff delta test for my data. I have question 1 to 10 (q1 to q10, in Likert-scale data 1 to 5). In another column (City) I have 8 cities. I would like to run the tests each time comparing 2 cities. How can I filter for 2 cities at the time?

This is my code as I have it now:

```
library("readxl")
library("effsize")
library("dplyr")
library("coin")
library("psych")

data <- read_excel('AllData3.xlsx')
city <- as.factor(data$City)

province_NH <- filter(data, city == "Amsterdam" | city == "Hoorn")

xtabs( ~ province_NH + q1,
   data = data)

wilcox.test(q1 ~ province_NH,
        data=data) 

cliff.delta(q1~province_NH)
```

I get this error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~province_NH + q1, data = data)
> :    invalid type (list) for variable 'province_NH'

Anyone knows how to run this?

Comment: You haven't given us your test data, so I can't be sure, but you're filtering `data` on an external vector (`city`) rather than on one of its columns (`City`).  That looks odd.  `Province_NH` is (or should be) a data frame, but you're using it as a term in a formula.  That is also odd.  Welcome to SO, but please realise you maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: How can I give you my test data?

Comment: Follow the advice in the post I linked to above.  It would also be useful to know what happens when you address the other points I raised.